# How to show the list of sqlite by order in android

Tags: android, sqlite, android-studio, cursor

I create an application for calculate university grades and I want to add an option to sort the database.

My database is based on sqlite and every time that I need to show the list of all the courses that were added by the user, I take them one by one and add the list Data Adaptar.
It always shows the course by insert order, and I want now to give an option for change the list order to By name of course/By year and more..

I attached the code of the activity, DataListActivity:

```
package com.example.ido.grades;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.ContextMenu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.util.Collections;

public class DataListActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
    ListView listView;
    SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase;
    CourseDbHelper courseDbHelper;
    Cursor cursor;
    ListDataAdaptar listDataAdaptar;
    Spinner sortSpinner;
    ArrayAdapter<String> sortAdapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.update_course);
        hideActionBar();
        sortSpinner = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.sortSpinner);
        String[] sortItems = new String[]{"Sort by","Course name","Year","Semester", "Grade", "Points"};
        sortAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, sortItems);
        sortSpinner.setAdapter(sortAdapter);
        listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_view);
        listDataAdaptar = new ListDataAdaptar(getApplicationContext(),R.layout.row_layout);
        listView.setAdapter(listDataAdaptar);
        registerForContextMenu(listView);
        courseDbHelper = new CourseDbHelper(getApplicationContext());

        sqLiteDatabase = courseDbHelper.getReadableDatabase();
        cursor = courseDbHelper.getInformation(sqLiteDatabase);
        registerForContextMenu(listView);
        View header = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.header, null);
        listView.addHeaderView(header);


        if (!cursor.moveToFirst()){
        }
        else {
            do {
                String year,semester,course,points,grade;
                year = cursor.getString(0);
                semester = cursor.getString(1);
                course = cursor.getString(2);
                points = cursor.getString(3);
                grade = cursor.getString(4);
                DataProvider dataProvider  = new DataProvider(year,semester,course,points,grade);
                listDataAdaptar.add(dataProvider);
            }
            while (cursor.moveToNext());
        }
    }
    public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v, ContextMenu.ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        if (((AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo)menuInfo).position == 0) {
            return;
        }
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_data_list, menu);

    }
    public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo info =
                (AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo) item.getMenuInfo();

        final int mySelectedRowIndex = info.position-1;


            switch (item.getItemId()) {
                case R.id.update_item:
                    courseDbHelper = new CourseDbHelper(getApplicationContext());
                    sqLiteDatabase = courseDbHelper.getReadableDatabase();
                    DataProvider raw2 = (DataProvider) listDataAdaptar.getItem(mySelectedRowIndex);

                    Intent i = new Intent(DataListActivity.this, UpdateCourseActivity.class);
                    String year = raw2.getYear();
                    String semester = raw2.getSemester();
                    String course = raw2.getCourse();
                    String points = raw2.getPoints();
                    String grade = raw2.getGrade();
                    int semIndex;
                    if (semester.equals("A'")) {
                        semIndex = 1;
                    } else if (semester.equals("B'")) {
                        semIndex = 2;
                    } else {
                        semIndex = 3;
                    }
                    i.putExtra("YEAR", year);
                    i.putExtra("SEMESTER", Integer.toString(semIndex));
                    i.putExtra("COURSE", course);
                    i.putExtra("POINTS", points);
                    i.putExtra("GRADE", grade);
                    i.putExtra("POS", Integer.toString(mySelectedRowIndex));

                    startActivity(i);


                    return true;
                case R.id.delete_item:
                    AlertDialog.Builder builder1 = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
                   DataProvider raw3 = (DataProvider) listDataAdaptar.getItem(mySelectedRowIndex);
                    builder1.setMessage("The course '" + raw3.getCourse() + "' Will delete, Are you sure?");
                    builder1.setCancelable(true);
                    builder1.setPositiveButton("Yes",
                            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                                    delete(mySelectedRowIndex);
                                    dialog.cancel();
                                }
                            });
                    builder1.setNegativeButton("No",
                            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                                    dialog.cancel();
                                }
                            });

                    AlertDialog alert11 = builder1.create();
                    alert11.show();

                    return true;
                default:
                    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
            }

        }

    public void onBackPressed() {
        startActivity(new Intent(this, MainActivity.class));
    }

    public void delete(int mySelectedRowIndex){
        courseDbHelper = new CourseDbHelper(getApplicationContext());
        sqLiteDatabase = courseDbHelper.getReadableDatabase();
        DataProvider raw = (DataProvider)listDataAdaptar.getItem(mySelectedRowIndex);
        courseDbHelper.deleteInformation(raw.getYear(), raw.getSemester(), raw.getCourse(), raw.getPoints(), raw.getGrade());
        Toast.makeText(this, "The course succesfully deleted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        finish();
        startActivity(getIntent());

    }
    private void hideActionBar() {
        //Hide the action bar only if it exists
        if (getSupportActionBar() != null) {
            getSupportActionBar().hide();
        }
    }
    }
```

CourseDBHelper.java:

```
package com.example.ido.grades;
import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.util.Log;

public class CourseDbHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    private static final String DATABASE_NAME  = "COURSEINFO.DB";
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;


    public String CREATE_QUERY = "CREATE TABLE " + UserCourse.NewCourseInfo.TABLE_NAME + "("+ UserCourse.NewCourseInfo.YEAR+" TEXT,"
            + UserCourse.NewCourseInfo.SEMESTER+" TEXT,"+ UserCourse.NewCourseInfo.COURSE+" TEXT,"+ UserCourse.NewCourseInfo.POINTS+" TEXT,"
            + UserCourse.NewCourseInfo.GRADE+" TEXT);";

    public  CourseDbHelper (Context context){

        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
        Log.e("DATABASE_OPERATIONS","Database created/opened...");
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        db.execSQL(CREATE_QUERY);
        Log.e("DATABASE_OPERATIONS", "Table created");

    }
    public void putInformation(String year, String semester, String course, String points,String grade,SQLiteDatabase db){
        ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
        cv.put(UserCourse.NewCourseInfo.YEAR, year);
        cv.put(UserCourse.NewCourseInfo.SEMESTER, semester);
        cv.put(UserCourse.NewCourseInfo.COURSE, course);
        cv.put(UserCourse.NewCourseInfo.POINTS,points);
        cv.put(UserCourse.NewCourseInfo.GRADE, grade);
        db.insert(UserCourse.NewCourseInfo.TABLE_NAME, null, cv);
        Log.e("DATABASE_OPERATIONS", "One raw inserted");

    }
    public double updateInformation(String old_course,String year, String semester, String course, String points,String grade,SQLiteDatabase db){
        ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
        cv.put(UserCourse.NewCourseInfo.YEAR, year);
        cv.put(UserCourse.NewCourseInfo.SEMESTER, semester);
        cv.put(UserCourse.NewCourseInfo.COURSE, course);
        cv.put(UserCourse.NewCourseInfo.POINTS,points);
        cv.put(UserCourse.NewCourseInfo.GRADE, grade);
        String Selection = UserCourse.NewCourseInfo.COURSE + " LIKE ?";
        String[] Selection_args = {old_course};
       double count =  db.update(UserCourse.NewCourseInfo.TABLE_NAME,cv,Selection,Selection_args);
        return count;
    }
    public Cursor getInformation(SQLiteDatabase db){
        Cursor cursor;
        String[] projections = {UserCourse.NewCourseInfo.YEAR,UserCourse.NewCourseInfo.SEMESTER,
                UserCourse.NewCourseInfo.COURSE, UserCourse.NewCourseInfo.POINTS,UserCourse.NewCourseInfo.GRADE};
          cursor=     db.query(UserCourse.NewCourseInfo.TABLE_NAME,projections,null,null,null,null,null );
        return cursor;
    }
    public void deleteInformation(String  year, String semester,
                                  String course,String points,  String grade){
        SQLiteDatabase db = null;
        try
        {
            db = this.getWritableDatabase();

            String where = UserCourse.NewCourseInfo.YEAR + " = ? AND "
                    + UserCourse.NewCourseInfo.SEMESTER + " = ? AND "
                    + UserCourse.NewCourseInfo.COURSE + " = ? AND "
                    + UserCourse.NewCourseInfo.POINTS + " = ? AND "
                    + UserCourse.NewCourseInfo.GRADE + " = ?";

            double iNumberDeleted = db.delete(
                    UserCourse.NewCourseInfo.TABLE_NAME,
                    where,
                    new String[]{year, semester, course, points, grade}
            );
            // you might want to evaluate the number of affected rows
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Log.d("DB_DELETE", "...your data..." + "\n" + ex.getMessage());

        }
        finally
        {
            if (db != null)
                db.close();
        }



    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

    }

}
```

DataProvider.java:

```
package com.example.ido.grades;

/**
 * Created by Ido on 08/08/2015.
 */
public class DataProvider {

    private String year;
    private String semester;

    public String getYear() {
        return year;
    }

    public void setYear(String year) {
        this.year = year;
    }

    public String getSemester() {
        return semester;
    }

    public void setSemester(String semester) {
        this.semester = semester;
    }

    public String getCourse() {
        return course;
    }

    public void setCourse(String course) {
        this.course = course;
    }

    public String getPoints() {
        return points;
    }

    public void setPoints(String points) {
        this.points = points;
    }

    public String getGrade() {
        return grade;
    }

    public void setGrade(String grade) {
        this.grade = grade;
    }

    private String course;
    private String points;
    private String grade;

    public DataProvider(String year, String semester,String course, String points, String grade){
        this.year=year;
        this.semester=semester;
        this.course=course;
        this.points=points;
        this.grade=grade;
    }
    }
```

I hope its enough to understand what i want.
Thanks!

***My new problem***

I have a problem when I try to sort the table by the grades score, for example, my database had the grades: 50,26,6,100,89.
It will show:
1. 89
2. 6
3. 50
4. 26
5. 100 
instead of:
1. 100
2. 89
3. 50
4. 26
5. 6

I need somehow to sort by integer and not by string, Thats the line code of the query:

```
cursor = db.query(UserCourse.NewCourseInfo.TABLE_NAME, projections, null, null, null, null, UserCourse.NewCourseInfo.GRADE +  " DESC");
```

Comment: what is your sorting criteria ??? depending on what you want to sort data?

Comment: @ZahanSafallwa , I attached the java of the database to the main post, and i want to sort by: Adding date, year,semester,course,points and grade.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
  public Cursor query(String table, String[] columns, String selection,
            String[] selectionArgs, String groupBy, String having,
            String orderBy)
```

hope you can understand by names. so you need to pass sort order for last parameter.

Since you have spinner with sort selection. just pass the selected sort coulmn  name to getinformation method.just past below code on Oncreate Method

```
sortSpinner = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.sortSpinner);
        String[] sortItems = new String[]{"Sort by","Course name","Year","Semester", "Grade", "Points"};
        sortAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, sortItems);
        sortSpinner.setAdapter(sortAdapter);
        listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_view);
        listDataAdaptar = new ListDataAdaptar(getApplicationContext(),R.layout.row_layout);
        listView.setAdapter(listDataAdaptar);
        registerForContextMenu(listView);
        courseDbHelper = new CourseDbHelper(getApplicationContext());

        sqLiteDatabase = courseDbHelper.getReadableDatabase();
        cursor = courseDbHelper.getInformation(sqLiteDatabase,UserCourse.NewCourseInfo.COURSE)
     sortSpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

                     if(position==0){
                         cursor = courseDbHelper.getInformation(sqLiteDatabase,UserCourse.NewCourseInfo.COURSE);


                     }else if(position==1){
                         cursor = courseDbHelper.getInformation(sqLiteDatabase,UserCourse.NewCourseInfo.YEAR);

                     }}

                @Override
                public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

                }
                });
```

Just pass SelectedSortOrder to getInformation method of your db helper class.

```
    public Cursor getInformation(SQLiteDatabase db, String SelectedSortOrder){
            Cursor cursor;

            String[] projections = {UserCourse.NewCourseInfo.YEAR,UserCourse.NewCourseInfo.SEMESTER,
                    UserCourse.NewCourseInfo.COURSE, UserCourse.NewCourseInfo.POINTS,UserCourse.NewCourseInfo.GRADE};
 if(SelectedSortOrder.equals(UserCourse.NewCourseInfo.COURSE)){
    cursor=  db.query(UserCourse.NewCourseInfo.TABLE_NAME,projections,null,null,null,null, UserCourse.NewCourseInfo.COURSE + " ASEC");
                return cursor;
            }

    else if(SelectedSortOrder.equals(UserCourse.NewCourseInfo.GRADE)){
cursor=     db.query(UserCourse.NewCourseInfo.TABLE_NAME,projections,null,null,null,null, UserCourse.NewCourseInfo.GRADE + " ASEC");
                return cursor;
    } elseif(AnotherTYPE){  }
```

or via raw query also you can perfom sort on database. You can replace sortorder by **ASEC  or DESC**

```
String orderBy ="select COLUMN_NAME from TABLE_NAME orderby ASEC ";
                 Cursor C=database_ob.rawQuery(orderBy, null);
```

**Edited: His new problem with Grade Scores**

```
 public String CREATE_QUERY = "CREATE TABLE " + UserCourse.NewCourseInfo.TABLE_NAME + "("+ UserCourse.NewCourseInfo.YEAR+" TEXT,"+ UserCourse.NewCourseInfo.SEMESTER+" TEXT,"+ UserCourse.NewCourseInfo.COURSE+" TEXT,"+ UserCourse.NewCourseInfo.POINTS+" TEXT,"+ UserCourse.NewCourseInfo.GRADE+" TEXT);";
```

You are storing GRADE as TEXT .you need to use [ORDERBY](http://www.1keydata.com/sql/sqlorderby.html)

**ORDER BY UserCourse.NewCourseInfo.GRADE DESC**

cursor = db.query(UserCourse.NewCourseInfo.TABLE_NAME, projections, null, null, null, null, "ORDER BY "+UserCourse.NewCourseInfo.GRADE +  " DESC");

With **integer** . you need to save as integer type data. pass as int. you can cast String to int as Integer.parseInt("your value")

```
 int grade;
 public void setGrade(int grade) {
        this.grade = grade;
    }
```

Comment: I try to work with the codes you give me, But i cant understand how to use them in my code (Except getInformation function). Its too match to ask from you to change my code and set the default of the sort will be by course name (UserCourse.NewCourseInfo.COURSE) ?, Then i hope i will understand better and change it for all the sort orders.

Comment: Updated my answer. Set spinner default selection as course name. pass the coursename get the data and set it to adapter(this will happen on app lauching ).and the whenever spinner item selected .pass the column name to that method and get the data update the arraylist and call notifydatasetchanged.

Comment: Hi, When I sort the table by grade its not working fine, Please check under ***My new problem*** In the bootom of my main post , I noted wih more details.

Comment: Updated ! Thank you. if you have any problem again . please post as new problem.or dont accept the answer until you finished work. thanks..

Comment: Thank you very much for your help! I didnt understand how can i use the first option you gave me (ORDER BY) in my code, So i tried the second option. I changed the GRADE from TEXT to integer (and INTEGER also), but the result are the same and 100 is still in the bottom of the list.

Comment: dude..I have used same desc for my table text column. it working for me.i gave you link and usage. you cant ask me to execute and run the program.

Comment: Thank you again for your help and sorry for bothering you. I think i found why it is working for you but not for me, The only time i used the CREATE_QUERY is when i create the database at the first time i runing the app (in onCreate function),  When i reinstall the app from zero it is work. One more thing, Can i update the execSQL with the new CREATE_QUERY String without reinstall the application ?

Comment: @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
//read doc.. you are working without reading.                 
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_NAME);
        onCreate(db);}

Comment: Add on CourseDBHelper. Java  please read documentation.. every ovverided method has purpose..

Answer (score 1):

You can just change the query like below to get data in sorted form

```
Cursor cursor = db.query(Your_table_name, new String[] {date, year,semester,course,points,grade},
    null, null, null, null, date + " ASC, " + semester  + " ASC");
```

1. Here `new String[] {date, year,semester,course,points,grade}` is the array of columns you want the data to read.
2. `date + " ASC, " + semester  + " ASC"` -- means that we want the data sorted in ascending order by date & semester. You can use `DESC` instead of `ASC` to order in reverse way.
3. You can add more data with `date + " ASC, " + semester  + " ASC"` in the same manner to get extra condition of sorting like `date + " ASC, " + semester  + " ASC, ",+ point + " ASC"`

**Note:**

Be careful about comma`s,plus sign & spaces in query

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I need to change that line in DataListActivity:         cursor = courseDbHelper.getInformation(sqLiteDatabase);
?